# "to be prejudice towards/against someone" vs "to be prejudiced against/towards someone"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is the correct form?

> He's **prejudice** against/towards women.
>
> He's **prejudiced** towards/against women.

Answer (score 9):

"Prejudice" is a noun.  You can't *be* prejudice -- instead you *have* a prejudice.

> He **has a prejudice** against eating what he considers "foreign" food.

Or you can say the same thing with "prejudice" as a verb, in this case expressed as a past participle adjective:

> He **is prejudiced** against eating what he considers "foreign" food.

Both are fine.  There is no difference in meaning.

> He **has a prejudice** against women
>
> He **is prejudiced** against women.

Side note:  Because "prejudice" is generally a *negative* condition, you have to be careful when using "prejudice *towards*" something.  This usually indicates a prejudice in the direction of some negative outcome:

> The judge ruled the evidence would unlawfully **prejudice** the jury **toward** convicting the defendant.

This means that when you say something like, "He is prejudiced *toward* women," it implies you *disapprove* of this attitude.  If you want to make a more neutral statement, you can instead use terms like "prefer", "incline toward", or "partial to".

Comment: Or, if it's something in favour of the thing, then *he has a bias for* it.

Comment: @JasonBassford I think of *bias* as similarly negative, although both can be nuanced.

Comment: The *act* is often negative (because nobody likes bias of any kind) but while it's awkward to say *a prejudice in favour of some group*, it's normal to hear *a bias in favour of some group* or *biased toward some group*.

Answer (score 4):

In the first usage "prejudice" is a **noun**, and in the second usage "prejudiced" is an **adjective**.

The usage as a descriptive noun might rarely be used *at a stretch* as

> He's prejudice personified

but the usual use is as the adjective "prejudiced".

About the choice of **against** and **toward**, these two examples show the difference.

> He's prejudiced against women.
>
> He's friendly towards beggars.
>   e that is unlikely to be used by a native speaker.

Comment: You can't be something negative **towards** someone?

Comment: You can be prejudiced towards someone or something, but usually it is against. "He is prejudiced towards members of his club". To put it another way, you can't be attracted *against* someone, or be repelled *towards* them.

Comment: You changed it and then it **became acceptable**. It was not at first at all.

Comment: "He's prejudice personified". ***I don't think that is a stretch at all.*** I think it is proper usage. My native language is English.

Comment: Oh ok — but "first" refers to the noun **usage** in both the question and the answer.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. Your word **first** sounded like it referred to the OP's ***first sentence***. I always thought ***prejudice personified was 100% right***, and I do not think it is a stretch. That's all.

Comment: @Lambie is the answer finally there?

Answer (score 2):

*Prejudice* is a **noun**, and *prejudiced* is an **adjective**. Let's say you were to say:

> He is **prejudice** against women.

Then you would be claiming that he, himself, is "prejudice against women", a concept or feeling or state of mind. That's a noun phrase. Being generous, we could assume you were describing him as the personification of such prejudice. That is highly unlikely to be anything you want to say.

But then there's:

> He is **prejudiced** against women.

This is a much more sensible thing to say. In that case, *prejudiced* is an adjective, and *against women* is a **complement** of that adjective, as it *completes* the meaning of *prejudiced*. Actually, the *against women* bit is a complement in the other case as well.

Now, a quick exploration of that *against*/*towards* thing. There's an argument that prejudice is an inherently negative concept, and philosophically it might be. As a word, though, it means to pre-judge, to judge in absence of evidence based on some characteristic. There's a school of thought that says that *prejudice toward(s)*<sup>1</sup> something is prejudice in that thing's favour, and *prejudice against* something is to that thing's detriment.

In my experience, some people have that assumption, and others don't. Personally, I see *prejudice against* as to the detriment, and *prejudice towards* as **neutral**. The expression for prejudice in favour would be *prejudice in favour of*. [NGram suggests that *against* is used more than the other forms put together](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prejudice%20against%2Cprejudice%20toward%2Cprejudice%20towards%2Cprejudice%20in%20favour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprejudice%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprejudice%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprejudice%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprejudice%20in%20favour%3B%2Cc0), though *in favour* used to be much more common than *toward(s)*.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Let's not get into the toward/towards debate here, though. It's rather tangential to the question.

Comment: Why even bother with the OP's first, incorrect sentence?? It's really unacceptable English.

Comment: @Lambie: Because it's not actually meaningless. It's just a meaning you are never likely to want to use. Explaining why that is will be more useful than just saying "don't do that".

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "prejudice against" is clear. But the meaning of "prejudice towards" could be seen as ambiguous.

The etymology dictionary:

"prejudice (v.) mid-15c., prejudicen, "to injure or be detrimental to," from prejudice (n.) and from Old French prejudiciier."

In this reading "prejudice" is clearly negative, implying "prejudice towards" has the same meaning as "prejudice against".

However it goes on:

"Meaning 'preconceived opinion' (especially but not necessarily unfavorable) is from late 14c. in English; now usually 'decision formed without due examination of the facts or arguments necessary to a just and impartial decision.' "

This comes from the the sense of prejudice as "pre-judge" - implying that "prejudice towards" is to pre-judge in favour of. However I believe that common usage has now overtaken this second definition, so that "prejudice towards" has the same meaning as "prejudice against". But the hint of ambiguity suggests use of "prejudice against" is the better choice in speech or writing.